# SIGABRT error issues in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sigabrt

I am new to Xcode and have an error on my app that is running on the newest version of Xcode and receive this error when I try to run my app. Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT".
And in the debugger I get this, terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c. All help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can you post your full backtrace for the exception?

Answer (score 5):

SIGABRT is the generic error message for "you've got a bug and your program has crashed."  So nobody can help you without more information.  First thing you should do is enable xcode's debugger to trap your error.  Assuming XCode 4, go to the breakpoint Navigator, and in the lower left corner, click the + button and add an Exception Breakpoint (Exception:Objective C, Break On Throw, Action and Options leave blank).  This will enable the debugger to catch your SIGABRTs and give you some clue as to where you are in the program.

For learning more about the debugger, you might start here... http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/03/debugging.html

Good luck

Comment: It didn't work, still. I'm gonna try and figure this out, but I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

macworths answer was great but I have one thing real quick for you to try. If you are using Interface Builder for a lot of you visual side of things, (i.e. you're not generating buttons, and views with code) you will get a SIGABRT every time you delete the code for an IBOutlet, but you don't delete the connection in the connections inspector. 1. Click on your NIB, 2. Click on File's Owner, and 3. Click on the Connections inspector.

[image]

Other than that, you'll have to use macworths answer to get more info, i think.

Comment: It didn't work, still. I'm gonna try and figure this out, but I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I've just 2 days solving one of these - SIGABT on every *second* launch of the iPhone app - but never on the iPad version of the app. None of the debugging tools helped unfortunately (XCode 4.6).

In the end I found the issue by going through every single element of the iPhone specific XIBs ... and found one of them had a button using an image file that was no longer in the project.

Once I removed that reference, the problem went away.